# How to navigate to a second viewController using a UIPickerview

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uipickerview

How to navigate between two viewcontrollers using a UIPickerview

I am trying to navigate between two viewcontrollers using a UIPickerview, so i first learned how to use didSelectRow to change the title of a label and then i tried using some code to navigate to another viewcontroller but that didn't work.

The code that i used was:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
var food = ["hello", "hi", "hey"]

var placementAnswer = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return food.count 
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return food[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    placementAnswer = row
}

@IBAction func labelChanged(sender: UIButton) {

    if (placementAnswer == 0){

    }else if (placementAnswer == 1){

        let view2 =     

self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! ViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

    }else if (placementAnswer == 2){

}
}
}
```